# My eclipse new maven project doesn't list all the archetpyes.very few were listing..how to fix it

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, maven-archetype

My eclipse new maven project doesn't list all the archetypes. very few were listing..how to fix it
I have create new maven project in the filter tab I entered Spring but nothing comesup. even the list looks very small compared what I usually remember

Answer (score 1):

As long as I remember Eclipse automatically provides the archetypes you have installed in your Maven local repository and also a set from Apache to create new Maven projects.

If you want to add new archetypes from a remote location like Maven Central, you will have to manually add an URL pointing to an *archetype-catalog.xml* file in the **Archetypes** preference page located in the **Eclipse Preferences** beneath the Maven node in the tree panel.

Comment: Thank you. I had to add https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml and i was able to see full list.

Answer (score 0):

you should let eclipse know about the archetype catalog file.[read this to understand about archetype catalog file](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-catalog.html)

1. Add remote cat file

[image]

2. select the newly added category when creating new Maven project

[image]

Enjoy !!!!